# Procedure or function 'TestTableInsert' expects parameter '@EDIPI', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a page that inserts user information into a SQL server. I want to check to make sure that the  database table doesn't already have the user EDIPI number in it and if it does not than it insert the new provided information. My error message is:

> Procedure or function 'TestTableInsert' expects parameter '@EDIPI', which was not supplied.

My btnSaveSP_Click should allow the user to insert the information in to the database but I believe my Stored Procedure is wrong.

My Button Code:

```
protected void btnSaveSP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();


        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("TestTableInsert", sqlconn);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@EDIPI", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtEDIPI.Text;
        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtFirstName.Text;

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlconn.Close();
    }
```

My Stored Procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestTableInsert] 
@EDIPI nvarchar(50),
@First nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TestTable where EDIPI = @EDIPI) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO TestTable (EDIPI,First)
    VALUES (@EDIPI, @First)
END
END
```

Comment: Your command is `sqlCmd` but you add your params to `sqlcomm`.

Comment: Slaps self in the face.. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose your con/cmd either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@EDIPI", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtEDIPI.Text;
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
```

into

```
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EDIPI", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtEDIPI.Text;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
```

Note that in the first you use sqlcomm while it should be sqlCmd